# mongoose $inc is not working would like to insert value increment by one

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to increment view field by one always when it hit this api but does not work

error :   Posts validation failed: view: Cast to number failed for value

```
view: {
  type: Number,
  default: 0
},



 async request(req, res) => { 
     const post = await PostsModel.findOne({ _id: post_id });
     post.view = { $inc: { view: 1 } };
     await post.save();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your way, you need to do `post.view = post.view + 1` instead of `post.view = { $inc: { view: 1 } };` because it will set the `view` field to be the object `{ $inc: { view: 1 } }`.

Or if you want to use `$inc`, you need to make an **update operation**. Something like:

```
await PostsModel.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: post_id }, { $inc: { view: 1 } });
```